# SQlite Update Statement in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-android-player

I have an SQlite table with 4 Columns in Xamarin app.
I've already inserted 3 columns and now i need an update statement to Update 4th column with some values using for loop.

(OR)

Please suggest any better/other method to do the same.

Comment: Can you provide table structure of your table in code, and also your update query. Perhaps also the error message in case it is not query problem.

Comment: @lee Thank u sir , i have solved using the code below,Sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to update the record in the sqlite DB?
If so you can use this model to update the record in the DB.`prijem.BCode` is PrimaryKey, we set the type of PrimaryKey is `int` and `AutoIncrement`, So, if the model's PrimaryKey is not equal zero, this record stored in the DB, we can update this record by the Model.

```
  readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _database;

    public PrijemDatabase(string dbPath)
    {
        _database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        _database.CreateTableAsync<Prijem>().Wait();
    }

public Task<int> SavePrijemAsync(Prijem prijem)
    {
        if (prijem.BCode != 0)
        {
            return _database.UpdateAsync(prijem);
        }
        else
        {
            return _database.InsertAsync(prijem);
        }
    }
```

Here is my model.

```
public class Prijem
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Unique]
    public int BCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirmName { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
}
```

Here is link about how to execute CRUD, you can refer to it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows

Here is a demo about it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/getstarted-notes-database/

Comment: Thanks for the help sir,i have solved using your code